# Locally Compactness of infinite product space

Tags: general-topology

R denote the set of real numbers, then how i show that countable product of R is not locally compact under product topology

Comment: This is not a question, but an assertion.

Comment: but i can't prove it. Marten W.

Answer (score 3):

The point $(0,0,0,........ )$ has no compact neighbourhood as every neighbourhood $U$ contains a neighbourhood  of the form $U_1 \times U_2 \times \dots  $  in which infinitely many $U_i$'s are $\mathbb{R}$ so $U$ can not be compact.

Answer (score 2):

- If a topological space is locally compact, then all its bases must contain some non-empty relatively compact sets.
- Due to continuity of the projections, compact subsets of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ are contained in $K_1\times K_2\times K_3\times \cdots$ for some collection of compact subsets $K_i\subseteq \Bbb R$.
- The sets in the form $U_1\times U_2\times\cdots\times U_m\times \Bbb R^{\Bbb N_{>m}}$ for some open sets $U_1,\cdots,U_m\subseteq \Bbb R$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$. None of these is relatively compact.